# How does respondsToSelector behave when there is a delegate present?

Tags: iphone, delegates, uitextfield

I recently tried to subclass UITextField and set the delegate to myself (found this trying ti solve my problem: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/241465-iphone-why-can-a-uitextfield-be-its-own-delegate.html)

```
@interface MyObject :UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate>
@end

@implementation MyObject

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect) frame
{
  if((self=[super initWithFrame:frame]))
  {
      self.delegate=self;
  }
  return self;
}

-(BOOL) respondsToSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    NSLog(@"responds to selector");
    return [super respondsToSelector:selector];
}

// Implement all the missing methods
@end
```

Calling a method defined on the interface results in an infinite recursion. I don't see anything in the Apple docs that defines how respondsToSelector is supposed to behave in the presence of a delegate.

Comment: BTW, I am just overriding respondsToSelector just to check that there is some infinite recursion going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCEHCCE) for `respondsToSelector` states the following:

> You cannot test whether an object
>   inherits a method from its superclass
>   by sending respondsToSelector: to the
>   object using the super keyword. [..]
>   **Therefore, sending respondsToSelector:
>   to super is equivalent to sending it
>   to self.** Instead, you must invoke the
>   NSObject class method
>   instancesRespondToSelector: directly
>   on the object’s superclass

It seems that this could be the cause for your recursion problem. I don't know if the delegate stuff is even related. Just a guess though.

Comment: I saw this. But I don't think it explains everything. The infinite recursion arises when you set the delegate to yourself. So callers to the delegate methods will check [obj.delegate respondsToSelector:@(blah)]. And obj.delegate is the obj. So the respondsToSelector implementation must be checking the delegate internally. But I can't find docs that says if this is standard behaviour, or peculiar to UITextField ...